# Jquery data table reload on event

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery data table as follows.

```
var table =$('#alertHistoryTable').DataTable({
                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "columns" : [
                                { title: "Alert Timestamp" },
                                { title: "Type" },
                                { title: "Message" },
                            ],
                        "ajax": {
                            "url" : "site/blocks/alert-table/ajax/alert-table.jag",
                            "type": "POST",
                            "data" : function (d) {
                                d.action = "getDataFromAlertTable",
                                d.tableName = tableName;
                                d.searchQuery = null;
                                d.entriesPerPage = $("#alertHistoryTable_length option:selected" ).val();
                            }
                        }
                        });

$('#tableContainer').append(table); 
$('#tableContainer').show();
```

I have a drop down to choose the tableName, and once the tableName is changed I need to resend the ajax request and fetch data from server. Can this be done? The default table(the default drop down option) is working perfecty. But i am unable to make it work once the dropdown option changes.

any suggestions?

Comment: parameterise the table name "tableName" from the dropdown & on change of dropdown redraw the table.

Comment: yes redrawing is the part that doesn't work for me. How to redraw it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this function to reload the DataTable when necessary:

```
table.ajax.reload(null, true);
```

The official documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: That helped.. Thanks :)